# SQL DB2/400 : check existence global temporary table

Tags: sql, temp-tables, db2-400

SQL DB2/400  : Does anyone knows how to check existence globale temporary table before déclare instruction in a SQL function ?

The statement "DECALRE" causes a crash of the SQL function if the temporary table is already created.

I use the instruction:
"if not exists ((select count (*) from session.TEMP_IDX)) then ..." but I have the impression that it does not work ...

Comment: I've tried this instruction with "QTEMP" :
if not exists ((  select count(1) from qtemp.TEMP_IDX)) then    
      DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_IDX 
      (ID SMALLINT NOT NULL , STR_COL int, STR_LOC int ,TARGET_STRINT CHAR(150), COLUMN_VALUE CHAR(150), EDLEVEL INT) with replace;
    end if;

  Is it right ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `with replace` clause of the `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` statement

That way it won't matter if the table is there or not.